# In q/kdb+, can I speed up Kadane's algorithm for the maximum subarray problem?

Tags: algorithm, performance, kdb

I'd like to implement Kadane's algorithm for the maximum subarray problem in q; [here is the Python code for the simplest flavor we can look at on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Empty_subarrays_admitted)

```
def max_subarray(numbers):
    """Find the largest sum of any contiguous subarray."""
    best_sum = 0
    current_sum = 0
    for x in numbers:
        current_sum = max(0, current_sum + x)
        best_sum = max(best_sum, current_sum)
    return best_sum
```

Just to simplify, I can run this in two separate loops, one for each line in the for-loop; so let's look at a simplified piece of code:

```
current_sum = 0
for x in numbers:
    current_sum = max(0, current_sum + x)
```

I can implement this in q as:

```
((|[0]) (+)::)\[0f;x]
```

My runtime (single-core) for a 9M-length list is about 3.2s; for comparison,  Python+numba takes 22ms, while only executing in q one of the two composed functions, `(+)/[0f;z]`, takes 5 ms.

Is there any way to achieve numba-like speeds in q? If not, I'd move this algorithm to C, but I'd like to know if there's a q-thonic way of speeding it up.

Comment: This piece of code may be faster than your example but I don't think it comes close to `numba`, have a look `{(|)/[0(0|+)\x]}`. It's largely similar anyway, may be similar or identical to your current solution.

Comment: Regarding the performance numbers, I think the Numba version is not optimal. Here is wild guess: you are working on floating-point array and the Numba code is latency bound so the processor spent most of its time stalling. If this is true, then you can significantly improve the Numba code (based on low-level properties of modern processors). This also means that the q code is more sub-optimal and I am pretty sure there is no chance to beat an optimized Numba code or even get similar performance.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth-Treliant Thanks! I get similar performance, but you've taught me a terser way to compose functions, thanks! :)

Comment: Or, since we’re talking compositions, max((0|+)\\)@. But Kadane tracks the max-so-far as it loops, while (0|+)\ leaves that job to the final aggregation.

Comment: In the edge case where all the numbers are negative, the `max` wrongly returns zero.

Comment: @SJT depends on convention; if by convention sum of empty set is zero, and empty set is allowed, then in that edge case it would still be correct

Comment: [Discussion](https://community.kx.com/t5/kdb-and-q/LeetCode-53-Maximum-Subarray/m-p/13405#M239) now on KX Community.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the comment -- do you think my 3-line numba code could be written in a way that would make it run even faster? Could you please tell me how? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Gabi The idea is to break the dependency chain so the CPU can execute more instruction per cycle (in parallel on the same core). This is not so easy here since the dependency is not artificial. In general, this problem is called a parallel scan and it can be also applied in sequential so the processor can better execute instructions. One naive way to improve the code using this idea is to compute the cumsum for values with an odd indices and then one for the even indices and then sum up the to so to find the result. Note that tiling is required so to efficiently use CPU caches.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I don't think I understand -- two reasons being 1) I'm not doing a cumulative sum -- it's not an operation that I could use interleaving for; and 2) wouldn't combining two cumulative sums into one be the same simple for loop I've written? Would it be possible for you to share some code? Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with avoiding that exact algorithm we can get the speed up to a lot closer to numba.

First define S to the the cumulative sum of list A, then each segment i to j of A has sum S[j]-S[i-1].
From there we can say that the maximum sum that ends at j is S[j]-min S[i] where i < j. We can calculate this easily in Q by:

```
{s-mins 0^prev s:sums x}
```

which we can then find the maximum by:

```
{max s-mins 0^prev s:sums x}
```

For me on a single core I am getting around 148ms which is a lot closer but obviously still not perfect.

Comment: The two functions don't seem to be equivalent:
`q)x` : `0.1137452 0.02948078 0.1916099 -0.2703385 0.1919531`; `q){(|)/[0(0|+)\x]}[x],{max s-0^prev mins s:sums x}[x]` : `0.3348358 0.2210906`

Comment: @Gabi apologies it should be mins 0^prev

Comment: Ah great this one works! Neat idea, it'll take me a bit to get my head around it. Also I think `{max s-mins 0f,1_prev s:sums x}`is sliiightly more efficient. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've been able to prove to myself that `{s-mins 0^prev s:sums x} ~ (0|+)\` using scalar math, but I'd like to be able to prove this at the list level -- is there a  branch of math / CS that deals with properties of running sums and running maxs? What sort of background would I need to have to be able to come up with such an answer as yours on my own? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Gabi Replacing `0^` with `0f,1_` recasts the list as mixed type and runs a 9M list (on my machine) 20x slower and uses 60% more memory. Replacing it with `0,1_` yields the same time/space as the `0^`.

Comment: The `(0|+)` solution fails on the all-negative edge case (returns 0), but this solution does not.

Comment: @Gabi I don’t know what math background helps here, but the Vector Dojo channel is all about practising finding vector solutions in q. Use this link to join: https://join.slack.com/t/iversoncollege/shared_invite/zt-1k1yj44ar-8pVGYSpjWb23vtkXRpyjQg

Comment: @SJT thanks I joined. I'd expect if input type matches type of zero it would be faster -- my input is floats; if your inputs are integers then i'd expect it to be slower. Re edge cases I mentioned in a comment on the main post -- there are different flavors of the max subarray problem -- where the empty set is allowed and where it isn't; the `(0|+)` solution does give the right answer for the allowed-empty-set problem; and now I'm noticing that removing the `prev` part of Nathan's solution matches (0|+) in behavior perfectly.